# Facebook Fogger App Not Working

Tags: facebook

I have tried to install the Facebook App on both my laptop and desktop running on Ubuntu 12.04. It downloads and installs just fine on both, but when I click on the icon it doesn't do anything.

I installed per the instructions found here:
[Facebook App Installation Instructions](http://www.7chip.com/2012/07/desktop-facebook-app-for-ubuntu-linux.html)

Answer (score 1):

This was remedied by downloading the Facebook app via the Ubuntu Software Center. Be sure to pick the one that says facebook-desktop.